# Why do I get 1D array instead of 2D array Index error for Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict income (70000+) based on specific categorical fields (Sex and Highest Cert, dip, deg) based on python code below.

I created a range for the average income and then specified the specific range of income (70000+) I wanted to predict using
(Sex and Highest Cert, dip, deg)

I have the following code. However, I get an error when I get to the One hot encoding part of the code. I am using python on visual studio. I have tried changing the categorical field to "Age", but it does not work. The code is below. Please how can I fix it? Thank you.

```py
 # %% read dataframe from part1
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_pickle("data.pkl")
 
#%%
import numpy as np
bins = [0, 30000, 50000, 70000, 100000, np.inf]
names = ['<30000', '30000-50000', '50000-70000', '70000-100000', '100000+']
 
df['Avg Emp Income Range'] = pd.cut(df['Avg Emp Income'], bins, labels=names)
 
#%% OHE of Avg empl income
for val in df["Avg Emp Income Range"].unique():
    df[f"Avg Emp Income Range_{val}"] = df["Avg Emp Income Range"] == val
 
#%% selecting data
x= ["Sex","Highest Cert,dip,deg"]
 
#%%
success = ["Avg Emp Income Range_70000-100000","Avg Emp Income Range_100000+"]
y = success
 
# %% split into training / testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=123)
 
#%%
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
 
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("ohe", enc, ["Sex","Highest Cert,dip,deg",])
    ],
    remainder="passthrough",
)
 
x_train = ct.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = ct.transform(x_test)
```

I get this error

> Error:
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) c:\Users\maria\Documents\Project Capstone 2\Z NO\machine L.py in 42 )
> 43
> ---> 44 x_train = ct.fit_transform(x_train)
> 45 x_test = ct.transform(x_test)
>
> c:\Users\maria\Documents\Project Capstone 2\Z
> NO\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py in
> fit_transform(self, X, y)
> 522         else:
> 523             self._feature_names_in = None
> --> 524         X = *check_X(X)
> 525         # set n_features_in* attribute
> 526         self._check_n_features(X, reset=True)
>
> c:\Users\maria\Documents\Project Capstone 2\Z
> NO\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py in
> _check_X(X)
> 649     if hasattr(X, '**array**') or sparse.issparse(X):
> 650         return X
> --> 651     return check_array(X, force_all_finite='allow-nan', dtype=np.object)
> 652
> 653
>
> c:\Users\maria\Documents\Project Capstone 2\Z
> NO\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
> 70                           FutureWarning)
> 71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
> ---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
> 73     return inner_f
> 74
>
> c:\Users\maria\Documents\Project Capstone 2\Z
> NO\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
> ensure_min_features, estimator)
> 621                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
> 622                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
> --> 623                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
> 624
> 625         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes
>
> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=['Sex'].
> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
> single feature or
> array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say, that you trainings data is

```py
x = ["Sex","Highest Cert,dip,deg"]
y = ["Avg Emp Income Range_70000-100000","Avg Emp Income Range_100000+"]
# splitting the data
x_train = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=123)
```

but what you encode is an array of a [tupel](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer([("ohe", enc, ["Sex","Highest Cert,dip,deg",])])
```

Now, if you call `ct.fit_transform(x_train)`, the encoded object `cf` expects the input to be of 1D size (because it was just encoded to be an array of tuples) but your data is a 2D-array, which raises the exception.

However, I assume that you rather wanted to use `x` and `y` as keys for the data matrix `df`:

```py
x = ["Sex","Highest Cert,dip,deg"]
y = ["Avg Emp Income Range_70000-100000","Avg Emp Income Range_100000+"]
# splitting the data
x_train = train_test_split(df[x], df[y], random_state=123)
```

It is helpful to use the debugging option or the execute the code step-wise in iPython so that you can keep track of the size of the arrays and if the code actually does what you thought it should be doing.

Comment: Thanks @max . I tried this it worked but finally gave me the error :                                  
   Target is multilabel-indicator but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples']                                                                    I believe this is because I am using two columns for the y. I might try changing the ranges and see what happens. Any other ideas?

Comment: yes and no. You are not calling a measure here (you are importing `precision_score` though, which may rise this error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269187/facing-valueerror-target-is-multiclass-but-average-binary). This is not part of your question anymore. Anyway, just add the parameter `average=None` to the function, which raised this error and you'll get the score for both labels.
BTW: It is much easier if you post the entire error message. I see that this is difficult in a comment

Comment: Thanks so much this worked. Just that I am getting zero precision and recall but I will post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` and `y` data are not set correct: You are just using the column headers as lists instead of the dataframe's values. Try setting:

```
x = df[["Sex","Highest Cert,dip,deg"]]
y = df[["Avg Emp Income Range_70000-100000","Avg Emp Income Range_100000+"]]
```

Comment: Thanks @rftr for your response. I tried this but it gave me the error :                                "Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames". I want to believe this is because I used numpy to create the ranges .  I am pretty new to python and machine learning. I will try and look for how to create ranges in pandas, maybe that will help? Any other ideas pls? Thanks

Comment: Okay. This error is raised by the column transformer which can only handle column strings when dealing with pandas DataFrames. Therefore you don't have to use a numpy array for `x` and `y`. I edited my answer.

Comment: This should normally work but I got that target is multilabel error. Once I changed precision to micro, it was fine. Thanks so much